# Moodle Plugin Testing

Tags: plugins, moodle

I am new to moodle plugin development, is the only way to develop a plugin is through an IDE? How would you go about testing the plugin within moodle from the IDE without having to install the plugin everytime? Is there a way to just refresh the moodle plugin database and edit the source files within the server so you can test as you go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you don't have to use an IDE, you can use any editor.

The plugin is upgraded if you change the version number in version.php.

You only need to increment the version number if you make changes that require an upgrade - such as database changes or capabilities.

Everything else you can test without installing.